# Serializing Array inside cosmos DB when using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I've the following format within my COSMOS DB document.

```
"Tag": "SPEEDSTER",
    "data": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-09-05T13:55:09.297Z",
            "jsonVersion": 1,
            "speed": 404
        }
    ]
```

While importing the schema within ADF copy pipeline, the array is not supported.  Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SQL query in the copy activity to design your schema of your cosmos db source data.

[image]

I tested above SQL based on your sample data, and it was copied to a txt file in the blob storage successfully.

```
select c.id,c.Tag,data.timestamp,data.jsonVersion,data.speed from c
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  It worked perfectly.  Here's the query I ended up using:

select c.eventprocessedutctime, cTag,data.assetTag,data.timestamp,data.jsonVersion,data.messageType,
data.speed,c.PartitionId,c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime from c join data in c.data
where data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' 
AND data.timestamp < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'

Answer (score 0):

what is your sink data store?

If you want to export the document as is, for example, to a json format file, you could use the export json as is feature. To achieve that, you could remove structure in your data set and translator in your copy activity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#importexport-json-documents

If you want to extract data out from the array, you could write your own query to do some transformation.

Comment: My sink was a data lake.  I had a data array object.  So I used SQL as suggested by you and Jay Gong and was able to get the data.  This is the query that I used:

select c.eventprocessedutctime, cTag,data.assetTag,data.timestamp,data.jsonVersion,data.messageType, data.speed,c.PartitionId,c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime from c join data in c.data where data.timestamp >= '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}' AND data.timestamp < '@{formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ' )}'